# Search SharePoint ULS Logs with Windows

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, logging

I have a standard/new Windows 2008 R2 install with SharePoint 2010 and am looking for a SharePoint expectation that occurred sometime during the last week.

So I open windows explorer, then go to the logs directory (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS). In the toolbar I can enter some search text (exception) or i can Ctrl-F which puts my cursor in the same search box. First it searches the filenames, comes back with no results, and then i click File Contents. And it comes back with still no results.

Now I think, maybe there are no errors, so i search for something that I know is in the log (w3wp), still no results.

In previous versions of windows, i could usually fix this by making *.log files read as text.
But apparently (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725753(WS.10).aspx) *.log files should already be read as text.

Any idea how to make the search, really search log files. I would prefer a solution that did not involve installing any 3rd party software (eg like ULSViewer), but registry/powershell settings are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OOTB txt search sucks without installing something like WIndows Search. ULSViewer is not an install, it's .NEt so just copying it to the machine should suffice.